# Significance of capacitor in this circuit

Tags: capacitor, schematics

[image]

In the above circuit, you can see there is capacitance of 10uf, GND connected to pin number 16, 29, 28, 25, 23 and many other points.. What is the significance of this capacitor.. Can we neglect this.. Sorry, I am not very good with electronics..

Comment: For success, I suggest you have a sheet of copper under the MCU, with these capacitors soldered to the copper. This is a GROUND PLANE, and life becomes much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16, 29, 25, 23 are directly connected to GND. 28 doesn't show any connection.

There are two capacitors and they are connected to pins 19,20,21,22.

Those pins (19-22) could be VCC supply pins and the presence of the capacitor filters out any noise on the voltage supply line. You should not remove those capacitors.

Those capacitors are better known as decoupling capacitors and they:

1) Smooth the supply rail and get rid of any voltage spikes and dips.

2) Prevent high frequency signal/noise from entering or leaving the circuit.

3) Provide the sudden burst of energy required by the micro-controller.